# Troubles moving errors from one page to another PHP

Tags: php, authentication, system, transfer

I am following PhpAcademy's tutorials on making a login system, and I'm very new to this all. Intstead of making a widget like he did, I made an entire page for the form of the login, called signin.php, and a validation page called login.php. The forms action is login.php, this is file, and I have an array errors[] stored in a php file global to all pages. I append a new error to it every time I get an error, this is all fine, but now I want my errors to appear under the form on the login page, how can I do this? Right now, the errors only appear in login.php. I have tried sending over errors using header, that didn't seem to work, and I tried to print the errors over there by simply outputting the errors array over there (because it's global), but that doesn't seem to print anything either. What can I do?

Comment: use $_SESSION to store your errors and access from the other page

Comment: $_SESSION is the best way as stated but you can also send error states using $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

Global does not mean it's global to all pages.  Global is only global for the current page. If you want data to persist between pages/redirects you either need to pass the data in url (i.e., `signin.php?error=Invalid username and password`. I don't like this method because you need to sanitize the error message and it makes the url ugly.) or you have to store it so you can retrieve it on the next page. The easiest option is to use $_SESSION. Here's an example:

**login.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // ...

    // You'll have to change my custom functions like form_has_errors to whatever
    // you're using in your code
    if (form_has_errors()) {
        // Store the error in the session
        $_SESSION['errors'] = form_get_errors();

        // redirect
        header('Location signup.php');
    }

    // ...
```

**signup.php**

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    // ...

    if (isset($_SESSION['errors'])) {
        // change this to something that displays the errors better
        print_r($_SESSION['errors']);

        // remove the error from the session so we don't display it twice
        unset($_SESSION['errors']); 
    }
```